# Collabs quicksetup - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: android-management-api, redirect-uri-mismatch

I want to create an enterprise so I can have android tablets running an app in locked mode. Running the quicksetup guide (collabs document) gives: Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.

I have correct client id and not using a secret ID since it is not given by google cloud when creating oauth2 client as "Android" type. The rest is the default values given in the collabs quicksetup. It seems like the redirect uri is not authorized but I am not given the chance to add authorised uri as for type "Web Application".

Any help would be highly appreciated!